# Python - Tkinter - unable to disable single radio buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am not able to disable single **radio buttons** in my **tkinter gui**.
I can only disable the last created set of buttons, the reason is because the matrix i use to store the handle to the buttons is not stored or returned correctly.
It only returns handles to the last created buttons.

This is the code to test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun May  9 10:02:18 2021

@author: stefaniecg
"""
import tkinter as tk

gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('title of the app')
gui.geometry("400x200") # (X * Y)

# constants
inc_crit = (('item_0',0,'desc0'),('item_1',1,'desc1'),('item_2',2,'desc2'),('item_3',3,'desc3'))
inc_opt = (('true',0,0),('false',1,1),('maybe',2,2))

# display radio buttons
inc_v = [None] * len(inc_crit)
inc_txt = [None] * len(inc_crit)
rad_btn = [[None]*len(inc_opt)] * len(inc_crit)
for i,[name,row,desc] in enumerate(inc_crit):
    inc_v[i] = tk.IntVar(); inc_v[i].set(2)
    for j,[optn,val,col] in enumerate(inc_opt):
        rad_btn[i][j] = tk.Radiobutton(gui,variable=inc_v[i],value=val)
        rad_btn[i][j].grid(row=row,column=col)
    inc_txt[i] = tk.Text(gui,width=30,height=1,font=(None,13))
    inc_txt[i].grid(row=row,column=3) 
    inc_txt[i].insert(1.0,desc)

# disable radio buttons
rad_btn[1][2].configure(state='disabled')
rad_btn[2][0].configure(state='disabled')
rad_btn[3][2].configure(state='disabled')

# launch gui
gui.mainloop()
```

This is the return of the **handles** of the radio buttons.
This is the problem: they all return handle to **radiobutton10,11,12**.

```
In [10]: rad_btn
Out[10]: 
[[<tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton10>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton11>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton12>],
 [<tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton10>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton11>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton12>],
 [<tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton10>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton11>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton12>],
 [<tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton10>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton11>,
  <tkinter.Radiobutton object .!radiobutton12>]]
```

so, with every buttons i try to disable: (code below)
always the last set of created radio buttons is disabled: i.e. radio buttons 11,12,13, because of the handles.

```
# disable radio buttons
rad_btn[1][2].configure(state='disabled')
rad_btn[2][0].configure(state='disabled')
rad_btn[3][2].configure(state='disabled')
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the line:

```py
rad_btn = [[None]*len(inc_opt)] * len(inc_crit)
```

will create a list of lists with all the rows referencing same instance of list (`[None]*len(inc_opt)`).

You need to change it to:

```py
rad_btn = [[None]*len(inc_opt) for _ in inc_crit]
```

It will create `len(inc_crit)` instances of individual list `[None]*len(inc_opt)`.